# Django dropdown filter with ajax?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I need to update my template when the user chooses a value of the dropdown list. Is there a possibility to do this with an ajax call or similiar? It would be perfect that if the user is selecting a value of the dropdown, this value would be send to my view and the content in my page would update without page refresh.

I tried different things but nothing worked... Any suggestion is welcome.

Here's my shortened code:

**models.py**

```
class Author(models.Model):
      id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
      author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      status = models.CharField(max_length=50)          

      [...]
```

**views.py**

```
def authors(request):
     authors = Author.objects.all()
     if request.method="GET":
         authors = Author.objects.filter(status = filter)
```

**template**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Choose status
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Staff</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Admin</a>
          [...]
  </div>
</div>

{% for author in authors %}
{{author.author}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you share your models.py?

Answer (score -1):

**template**

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'admin' %}">Staff</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'staff' %}">Admin</a>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^admin/', authors_admin, name='admin'),
url(r'^staff/', authors_staff, name='staff'),
```

**views.py**

```
def authors_admin(request):
     authors = Author.objects.all()
     if request.method="GET":
         authors = Author.objects.filter(status = 'admin')
         return render(request, 'template.html', {
                  'authors ': authors 
         })

def authors_staff(request):
     authors = Author.objects.all()
     if request.method="GET":
         authors = Author.objects.filter(status = 'staff')
         return render(request, 'template.html', {
                  'authors ': authors 
         })
```